# How do I replace the shoulder belt on the 1991 Toyota Corolla?

Tags: toyota, corolla, installation

How do I replace the shoulder belt on an old 1991 Toyota Corolla?  The shoulder belt and lap belt are not connected (that is, NOT three-point).  The current shoulder belt is badly frayed on the driver side, and it is my understanding that the entire belt assembly kit (containing both shoulder belts - one for the driver side and one for the passenger side) must be replaced.  Can anyone tell me how to remove the current kit and install a new one?

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

I've done a quick search and found this image for a 1991 Corolla, manual, sedan, for the canadian market. You have 2 bolts to remove, the one on the top of the pillar and the one that attach both end of the seat belt. They may be hidden Under some plastics panel. It should be an easy task but make sure to tighten the bolt back!!

[image: 1991 Corolla front seat belts assembly]